# Calling input() from a vnoremap adds a space

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, macvim

Consider the following vimscript which I have added to an ftplugin ("~/.vim/ftplugin/tex.vim"):

```
vnoremap ,test <Esc>:call TestFunc(input("input:"))<CR> 
inoremap ,test <Esc>:call TestFunc(input("input:"))<CR>

fun! TestFunc(name)
        execute "normal! i" . a:name
endfun
```

My problem is that calling this from visual mode adds an initial whitespace, while it doesn't do this in insert mode:

If I type `,test` while in insert mode, I get `input:` in the command line. But if I type `,test` in visual mode, I get `input:`  in the commandline (*notice the trailing space*).

This space is then added as the first character to the argument of `TestFunc`, so that if I type `hello` as input, `TestFunc` adds `hello` to the document if I started from insert mode, but  `hello` if I started from visual mode.

Why is the whitespace added, and how do I get rid of it?

(I am using MacVim with Vim 8.2.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:help input()` says:

> Note: When input() is called from within a mapping it will consume remaining characters from that mapping, because a mapping is handled like the characters were typed.

There is a trailing space on your first line so `input()` "consumes" it, which makes it the first character of the input text. The solution, here, is simply to remove that trailing space.

The proposed example, with `inputsave()` and `inputrestore()`, is a bit over the top for this specific case but it is probably safer to systematically use that pattern.

FWIW, enabling the display of trailing spaces and other special characters is always a good idea: see `:help 'list'` and `:help 'listchars'`.

Comment: Thanks! Really annoying that I didn't catch that space.

Answer (score 0):

Your first line

```
vnoremap ,test <Esc>:call TestFunc(input("input:"))<CR>
```

has a trailing whitespace. Get rid of that, and it will behave as you wish.

I guess the reason is the following. The first part `:call TestFunc(input("input:"))<CR>` tells Vim to execute the code before `<CR>`. Vim does the job as told; it shows the input prompt, and remembers to call `TestFunc()` once the input is given. But then, you (i.e., the vnoremap) strikes one more key:  . This is like you're striking the spacebar when the input prompt is active. You can test this by replacing the trailing whitespace with something else.